# Equal function in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write an equal function that tell that any two numbers are equal, and that a symbol is equal only to itself. Also two lists should be equal if all their elements are recursively equal. I wrote a small equal function below, but it doesn't exactly achieve what I want.

```
(defun equal (x y)
   (if (atom x)
      (eql x y)
      (if (atom y)
         'nil
         (if (equal (car x) (car y))
             (equal (cdr x) (cdr y))
             'nil))))
```

Some of the tests cases that my function should satisfy are:

```
(my-equal 2.2 3) -> T
(my-equal 2.2 'a) -> NIL
(my-equal '(b 4 (c d (2.2)) e) '(b 2 (c d (0)) e)) -> T
(my-equal '(b 4 (c d (2.2)) e) '(b 2 (5 d (2.2)) e)) -> NIL
```

Please note that I want to only use the basic Lisp operations, the existing `equal` functions, `reverse`, `append`, `null`, `nil`, `listp`, `atom`, `cdr`, `car`, etc. No stuff like map, or other more sophisticated functions.

Comment: How come `2`, `2.2`, `3`,  and `0` is the same value?

Comment: `equal` is an ANSI CL function; you should not redefine it.

Comment: It might be a different package...

Comment: you define a function EQUAL, but your example calls MY-EQUAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (assuming the name of the new function is `my-equal`):

```
(defun my-equal (x y)
  (cond ((numberp x) (numberp y))
        ((symbolp x) (eq x y))
        ((and (consp x) (consp y))
         (and (my-equal (car x) (car y)) (my-equal (cdr x) (cdr y))))
        (t nil)))

(my-equal 2.2 3)  ;; => T
(my-equal 2.2 'a)  ;; => NIL
(my-equal '(b 4 (c d (2.2)) e) '(b 2 (c d (0)) e))  ;; => T
(my-equal '(b 4 (c d (2.2)) e) '(b 2 (5 d (2.2)) e))  ;; => NIL
```

The last case could be replaced by something like `(t (primitive-equal-function x y))` (or other cases) if you care for some test of equality when `x` and `y` are strings, characters, etc.